# Running some data analysis program but the last figure doesn't show?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-mining

There is some data analysis work need us to process. It is about some industry background data. The target is to analyze such data and mining some patterns from such data. The data files are simple ones presented as simple text format. It is about some thermal power generation and to predict the steam produced each case.
The data analysis program runs as the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats


###import warnings
###warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")





import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(pathname)s[line:%(lineno)d] - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('debug info')
logging.info('info info')
logging.warning('warning info')
logging.error('error info')
logging.critical('critial info')





##%matplotlib inline



train_data_file = "./steam_train.txt"
test_data_file = "./steam_test.txt"



train_data = pd.read_csv(train_data_file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
test_data = pd.read_csv(test_data_file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')



train_data.info()
test_data.info()


test_data.describe()
test_data.describe()


train_data.head()
test_data.head()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 6))
sns.boxplot(train_data['V0'],orient="v", width=0.5)



column = train_data.columns.tolist()[:39]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 40))
for i in range(38):
    plt.subplot(13, 3, i + 1)
    sns.boxplot(train_data[column[i]], orient="v", width=0.5)
    plt.ylabel(column[i], fontsize=8)
plt.show()


def find_outliers(model, X, y, sigma=3):
    # predict y values using model
    try:
        y_pred = pd.Series(model.predict(X), index=y.index)
    # if predicting fails, try fitting the model first
    except:
        model.fit(X, y)
        y_pred = pd.Series(model.predict(X), index=y.index)

    # calculate residuals between the model prediction and true y values
    resid = y - y_pred
    mean_resid = resid.mean()
    std_resid = resid.std()

    # calculate z statistic, define outliers to be where |z|>sigma
    z = (resid - mean_resid) / std_resid
    outliers = z[abs(z) > sigma].index

    # print and plot the results
    print('R2=', model.score(X, y))
    print('Mse=', mean_squared_error(y, y_pred))
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')

    print(len(outliers), 'outliers;', ' ALL data shape:', X.shape)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    ax_131 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
    plt.plot(y, y_pred, '.')
    plt.plot(y.loc[outliers], y_pred.loc[outliers], 'ro')
    plt.legend(['Accepted', 'Outlier'])
    plt.xlabel('y')
    plt.ylabel('y_pred');

    ax_132 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
    plt.plot(y, y - y_pred, '.')
    plt.plot(y.loc[outliers], y.loc[outliers] - y_pred.loc[outliers], 'ro')
    plt.legend(['Accepted', 'Outlier'])
    plt.xlabel('y')
    plt.ylabel('y - y_pred');

    ax_133 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    z.plot.hist(bins=50, ax=ax_133)
    z.loc[outliers].plot.hist(color='r', bins=50, ax=ax_133)
    plt.legend(['Accepted', 'Outlier'])
    plt.xlabel('z')

    plt.savefig('outliers.png')

    return outliers



from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
X_train = train_data.iloc[:,0:-1]
y_train = train_data.iloc[:,-1]
outliers = find_outliers(Ridge(),X_train,y_train)





plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

ax=plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.distplot(train_data['V0'],fit=stats.norm)
###plt.show()
ax=plt.subplot(1,2,2)
res = stats.probplot(train_data['V0'], plot=plt)
plt.show()


'''
train_cols = len(train_data.columns)
plt.figure(figsize=( train_cols, 4 ))

i = 0
for col in train_data.columns:
    i += 1
    ax = plt.subplot( train_cols , 4,  i)
    sns.distplot(train_data[col], fit=stats.norm)

    i += 1
    ax = plt.subplot( train_cols , 4 , i)
    res = stats.probplot(train_data[col], plot=plt)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
'''


train_cols = 6
train_rows = len(train_data.columns)
plt.figure(figsize=(4 * train_cols, 4 * train_rows))

i = 0
for col in train_data.columns:
    i += 1
    ax = plt.subplot(train_rows, train_cols, i)
    sns.distplot(train_data[col], fit=stats.norm)

    i += 1
    ax = plt.subplot(train_rows, train_cols, i)
    res = stats.probplot(train_data[col], plot=plt)
plt.show()
```

But after running the last line of code, it doesn't show the last figure. What's wrong with the above code?
And when I run the code in the commandline, the last group of the diagrams are distorted, see [image: the distorted image]. What could be the cause?

The conda environment code running in is:

```
...

dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - ca-certificates=2021.7.5=h06a4308_1
  - certifi=2021.5.30=py38h06a4308_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - openssl=1.1.1k=h27cfd23_0
  - pip=21.2.2=py38h06a4308_0
  - python=3.8.11=h12debd9_0_cpython
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - setuptools=52.0.0=py38h06a4308_0
  - sqlite=3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=0
  - pip:
    - cycler==0.10.0
    - joblib==1.0.1
    - kiwisolver==1.3.1
    - matplotlib==3.4.3
    - numpy==1.21.2
    - pandas==1.3.2
    - pillow==8.3.1
    - pyparsing==2.4.7
    - pysocks==1.7.1
    - python-dateutil==2.8.2
    - pytz==2021.1
    - scikit-learn==0.24.2
    - scipy==1.7.1
    - seaborn==0.11.2
    - six==1.16.0
    - sklearn==0.0
    - threadpoolctl==2.2.0

...
```

About the required data files can be downloaded from here: [data files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XhODutgobRvIVghDLVrCwjMiKZ_Sb88b/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe... [plt.show() does nothing when used for the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452455/plt-show-does-nothing-when-used-for-the-second-time)

Comment: The last line of code is not the second time to call plt.show(). Formerly called plt.show() several times and all showed the specific figure.

Comment: @MDR Perhaps you are wrong... The former block of code has similar logic and it shows figiures, but the last block of code doesn't. Have you ever run this snippet of code? What modification did you make to show the last figure?

Comment: This seems to be a naive question. Why no one answers?

Comment: Copied the code, as expected: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './steam_train.txt'`

Comment: @MDR Have you downloaded the required dataset files from the linkage in the last line of my question?

Comment: It seems participants in StackOverflow is not so active. Does anyone please recommend some paid forum where such questions could be solved very soon?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: FYI: this is what I get... https://ibb.co/4ZBQwTC.  Is this missing something or the same as you?

Comment: @MDR Under my environment, the last groups of images shown in [ibb.co/4ZBQwTC](https://ibb.co/4ZBQwTC) just doesn't show! What could be the cause?

Comment: @MDR The image was shown but distorted. What could be the cause?

Comment: @MDR Dear, have you seen the distorted image shown at the last part of this post? What is the cause? What tricks had you applied to produce the correct result?

Comment: I just downloaded the zip file and extract, pasted your code shown above into a new notebook, changed the path to the sub folder `steam` (shouldn't affect anything) and hit the run button.  Example: https://ibb.co/bXxbCNg

Comment: btw, (as I was doing a...) fresh install of Linux and Anaconda and update to Spyder to 5.0.5 (if I remember correctly) I thought I'd run your code.  It works as well: https://ibb.co/vBDgP6w (i've shared more about my environment than you :o).

Comment: @MDR Hey, MDR, Could you please check the conda environment I have included in the post(the newly added last part)? What have you seen if you run the program in command line?

Comment: i don't know the exact command you are running there.  if you are thinking of comparing versions, you can jump to assuming the Linux install is the latest.  have you considered changing where you are running it from (notebook, lab, spyder, change browsers, shake something loose)? new environment etc?  or perhaps if you save the image does it appear ok?  all things to test.

Comment: @MDR The distorted image of the graphs I uploaded is just generated from I run the python program in command line under the anaconda environment I have illustrated in this post!

Comment: I'm honestly going to be no use because I cannot recreate.  If the command line isn't working try Spyder (for example) and shake something loose.  Best I can say unfortunately :o(.  Otherwise close this question yourself and post a fresh one - maybe you just had bad timing when posting this question.  Maybe a new question will draw more interest.  Also, if the answer is important to you [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to it.